# Android - Firebase invites returns error - Resultcode 0 - Emails sent SMS not sent

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript, firebase-invites

In my nativescript-angular app, I am using the nativescript-plugin-firebase to implement firebase invites. I have setup both the SHA 1 and SHA 256  in the firebase console I have used the boilerplate code shared in READ.ME to test the invites (see below).

```
firebase.invites.sendInvitation({
  title: "Invite title here",
  message: "Invite message here"
}).then(
    function (result) { // SendInvitationResult
      console.log(result.count + "invitations sent, ID's: " + JSON.stringify(result.invitationIds));
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("sendInvitation error: " + error);
    }
);
```

I find that while on IOS the send invite function works as expected. On android I face 2 issues:

1. Email invitation is sent to the invitee but an error `Resultcode: 0` is returned and I do not get back the invitation ID
2. SMS invite is not sent to the invitee.

A similar issue has been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921875/firebase-invites-sends-emails-but-not-sms-returns-resultcode-0) - but there are no suggestions on what can be done to fix the error. 
Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/750) there seems to be a bug in Firebase's Invitations for Android Oreo and newer devices.

**Update:** Starting January 24th 2019 [Firebase Invites is deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=firebase_invites_deprecation).